# What does chmod g=- do?

Tags: permissions

I'm wondering what do the `+`/`-` signs do in `chmod`?

So for example, what does command `chmod u=-` do? My understanding is that it does nothing, because it lacks `r`/`w`/`x`. Is it correct? In order to actually do something, we would have to specify which permission we want to add or subtract.

Answer (score 13):

`=` with no permission bits [clears all the permission bits corresponding to “who”](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html):

> Clear the file mode bits specified by the **who** value, or, if no **who** value is specified, all of the file mode bits specified in this volume of POSIX.1-2017.

`-` with no permission bits doesn’t do anything:

> If **perm** is not specified, the `'-'` operation shall not change the file mode bits.

`chmod g=-` is interpreted as `chmod g= g-` and clears all the group permission bits. `u=-` does the same for the owner permission bits.

On their own, as you surmise, `-` and `+` don’t change anything if no permission bits are specified. Since you’re combining them with `=`, you see the effects of `=`.